# Spotify needs a lot of restarts to start properly

Tags: 22.04, spotify

I am on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I noticed that upon starting Spotify, it does not start immediately.  Also I have to force close it at most 5 times before the next start up works.  Also, by that time, it actually needs a bit more time for Spotify to "run" kinda like an engine "warming up" before running properly.

This is what I get when starting Ubuntu from the terminal

```
:~$ spotify (spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.646: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1422:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name (spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.649: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3308:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name (spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.650: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3770:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) –

[libprotobuf ERROR ../core/vendor/protobuf3/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:577] String field 'spotify.event_sender.proto.DroppedEvents.DroppedEventsBySequenceIdEntry.key' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
```

Comment: Sounds like a good issue to bring up to Spotify support.

Comment: Working fine here - Ubuntu 22.04 and Spotify installed as snap. How did you install yours?

Comment: I went to "Ubuntu Software" the one that you click on the side... and just installed it with normally.  Also, I find this message in the terminal when trying to run it via terminal:

Comment: :~$ spotify

(spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.646: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1422:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.649: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3308:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(spotify:42654): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:16:03.650: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3770:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)

Comment: [libprotobuf ERROR ../core/vendor/protobuf3/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:577] String field 'spotify.event_sender.proto.DroppedEvents.DroppedEventsBySequenceIdEntry.key' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. 
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)


I had to chop my comments to 3 parts.

Comment: Please don't paste relevant output into comments, edit your question and paste them there.